# C++ add-ons to Node, non blocking?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

Making a fairly large web application with Node, and running into the concept of c++ add-ons, and being completely new to the concept, I wonder; are add-ons written in C++ for Node.js blocking the thread?

For example a mathematical algorithm, running asynchronous of course, that if implemented in JS would block the thread.

Comment: This is interesting. So your asking what it's lifetime is really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native code add-ons can be written either blocking or non-blocking.  For example, `fs.readFile()` and `fs.readFileSync()` each have native code add-on implementations (they happen to be built-in add-ons, but the interface is largely the same).  So, it depends upon how you implement the add-on functions for whether they will have an asynchronous interface (and communicate results back via the event queue) or just be blocking functions.

A mathematical computation in native add-on code would have to create it's own native thread or process in order to run asynchronously and non-blocking.  But this can certainly be done.

You could prototype something like this by just putting the code in another process (written in any language) and then communicating with it from node.js via an http interface.  You don't even have to do it via a node.js add-on.

Comment: Thank you! So if I understand your comment correctly; a C++ add-on, a function that does its job and then calls a JS callback function via the V8 API, would still run in the same process and thread as Node itself?

Comment: @AxelBoberg - That is my understanding.  As an example, to implement the asynchronous `fs.readFile()`, node.js uses a thread pool and the actual asynchronous operation occurs on a separate native thread.  There is no automatic separate thread for an add-on function that would automatically allow JS to not block.  If you want your operation to be async and run in a separate thread or process, you have to code it to do so.